# NuxtJs Computed property "isLoggedIn" was assigned to but it has no setter

Tags: javascript, vuex, nuxt.js

For some reason i keep getting this error no matter what I try.

[image]

This is how I'm getting and updating the computed property

```
  computed: {
    isLoggedIn() {
    return this.$store.state.user.isLoggedIn;
   }
  },
  methods: {
   handleAuthenticate(value) {
     this.$store.commit("user/authenticate", value);
   }
  }
```

I've already looked up similar answers here and this doesn't fix the issue

```
computed: {
  isLoggedIn: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.state.user.isLoggedIn;
    },
    set(newValue) {
    this.$store.commit("user/authenticate", newValue);
   }
  }
},
```

I'm wondering if this is because I'm using Nuxt instead of just plain Vuejs. I followed the example on Nuxt official doc but still getting the error everytime i call my `handleAuthenticate` method:

https://nuxtjs.org/examples/vuex-store/
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/vuex-store?from-embed

this is the structure of my current user state and mutations

**state.js**

```
export default () => ({
  isLoggedIn: false
})
```

**mutations.js**

```
export default {
 authenticate(state, value) {
 state.isLoggedIn = value;
 }
}
```

**getters.js**

```
   export default {
    isLoggedIn(state) {
     return state.isLoggedIn
    }
   }
```

i'm not exactly sure what the problem is as i followed the example. Maybe i missed something. Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Can you please let me know if you're using the nuxt-auth package https://auth.nuxtjs.org/?

Comment: @ATULKUMARSINGH i'm not using nuxt-auth. For now i'm only just testing it. with a button toggle. I've already fixed it. so i'll post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those who encountered a similar issue. It turns I was received the error because i was using the `isLoggedIn` with v-model property.

```
 <v-navigation-drawer
  v-model="isLoggedIn"
  :mini-variant="miniVariant"
  :clipped="clipped"
  fixed
  app
>

</v-navigation-drawer>
```

I fixed it by returning the value on set method

```
isLoggedIn: {
  get() {
    return this.$store.state.user.isLoggedIn;
  },
  set(val) {
    return val;
  }
}
```